# Drupal8 module development: hook_node_access not called

Tags: hook, drupal-8

for my current site I have a content type that stores a user in an entity reference field. I want to allow the user referenced in this field to edit the data of that node. In drupal7 I would do that with a node_access hook - which I am not getting to work in drupal8.

Here is a demo code of my hook - for testing purposes I want to forbid everything. However it is never called, and no - I am not logged in as user1. Also reseted cache, uninstalled and installed the module again and rebuilt the permissions - nothing seems to make this hook work.

```
function mymodule_node_access(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node, $op, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account) {
    $access = new AccessResultForbidden();
    return $access;
}
```

My question is why is this hook never called - and if there is now with drupal 8 a better way to do so?
Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards,
Rambazamba

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

This hook is never called for user 1, since he bypasses every access control.

Try testing anonymously or as another role.

Comment: It's also never called for anyone who has the "Bypass content access control" permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command. The tool 'drupal console' is required.

```
drupal node:access:rebuild
```